# Spring framework 2.5 validate multiple form fields with the same errorcode

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there a way to reject multiple command object's fields with the same errorCode?
I know there in no such method in the Errors object as "errors.rejectValue(fieldsOfCommandsObject[],errorCode" bu this is what I want to do.
Google wasn't helpful so any help would be really appriciated
thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there are no other ways of doing that but calling `rejectValue()` multiple times for each command object bound.

Comment: thank you for answering.Yes, but if I use rejectValue I'll get the error message as many times as the fields are.And this is something I really don't want.

Comment: You may then put a global error and examine for duplicates before you add the same error again.